# Rx-PDO Application

Tags: can-bus, canopen

**RX configuration**

To configure an RX-PDO, three object categories in the object dictionary must be taken into account:

1-The objects that describe the functionality of the mapping.

2-The objects that describe the content of the mapping.

3-The objects that are to receive the received data. Configuration of the functionality (communication parameter)

The configuration of the first mapping is stored in the subindices of object 1400h. The second mapping is configured in 1401h and so on. In the following, we refer to 140Nh. Here, the configuration affects the COB-ID of the PDO message and the transfer type.

Objects 140Nh have only three subindices:

Subindex 0 (max. subindex): Total number of subindices

Subindex 1 (COB-ID): The COB-ID is stored here. For PDO mappings 1–4 (1600h–1603h), the CAN-ID is fixed depending on the node-ID and only the valid bit (bit 31) can be set in the COB-ID. From 1604h–1607h, the CAN-ID can be set independently (with the restriction that it not be used by other services, see table at the start of chapter CANopen services) as can the valid bit. The change of a COB-ID does not take effect until after the controller or communication is restarted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPZZF.png)

According to the above content, where is object 140N in the Object Dictionary? And how should we communicate with it?

Comment: "where is object 140N in the Object Dictionary?" What do you mean? 140N is the OD address.

Comment: @Lundin I meant 1400-1401-1402-... but I don't understand how these addresses are sent to 1600 like the picture in the question.

Comment: Ah so you mean where 1400 is mapped to? It depends on Device Profile and there's default mappings. As for how a TDPO from 1401 communicates with another node's RPDO, it doesn't, until you configure the COBID of either node's PDO to match the other.